# Is there an API for creating or managing custom directories in G Suite?

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api

In G Suite you can create custom directories for specific organisational units. However, I need to be able to manage this using the Directory API or similar. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Basically I need to be able to create a custom directory and then move groups into them.

Comment: I suspect that the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) is it, but haven't confirmed that yet. I'm actually looking for this answer myself.